# Ensure unique value for column in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I have implemented a custom `QTableView` and `QAbstractTableModel`. The `QTableView` uses the `Qt`-default text line edit delegate for manipulating string data. I would like to ensure that, after submitting an edit (pressing `enter`), the string is unique for its column. If another row has the same value for that column, the edit will be rejected, perhaps with a popup box, and then the text line edit will be programmatically put back into edit mode so the user can try again.

I have thought about using a custom delegate and possibly communicating between the delegate and the table view via signal and slots. The delegate could ensure that the value is unique inside `setModelData()`. To do this it would have to be injected with knowledge about the other columns. If the value is not unique, the delegate could emit a signal that the table view would pick up; something like `notUniqueTryAgain()`. Inside that slot the table would pop up a message and then call `edit()` on the cell. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: It depends on your model, but I'd write a boolean member function in the model which tells you if that data is unique for that column or not.  For this, you do not need signals & slots.  Cast QStyledItemDelegate::model() to your subclassed model and call the member function directly.  This could seriously impact performance though if your data is large.  In  such a case you'd want to keep the data in some type of container with fast look-up.  std::unordered_map, for instance.

Comment: Gotcha. How would you solve the problem of programmatically putting the cell back into edit mode? For that I believe we need access to the QTableView which neither the delegate nor model know about

Comment: That part I didn't think of.  As per before, I've not done a lot of user-editable models.  A signal/slot might work, or you could probably just use loop within the same function in the Delegate, no?

Comment: I want to explain why I added C++ tag, in your question I didn't see which language was used, without c++ tag my answer can't be very clear(maybe you use python)You accepted my answer, thank you, and now I see that you are really use c++, so I added this as a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use next delegate:

```
#ifndef ITEMDELEGATE_H
#define ITEMDELEGATE_H

#include <QItemDelegate>

class ItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget * editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // ITEMDELEGATE_H
```

Cpp

```
#include "itemdelegate.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDebug>

ItemDelegate::ItemDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *ItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
                                    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QLineEdit *editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
    return editor;
}


void ItemDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                 const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString value =index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
    QLineEdit *line = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    line->setText(value);
}


void ItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor,
                                QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QLineEdit *line = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    QString data = line->text();

    int column = index.column();

    for(int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); i++)
    {
        QModelIndex cur = model->index(i,column);
        qDebug() << data << model->data(cur, Qt::EditRole).toString();
        if(data == model->data(cur, Qt::EditRole).toString())
        {
            model->setData(index, "wrong");
            return;
        }
    }

    model->setData(index, data);
}


void ItemDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
                                        const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                        const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

Usage:

```
ItemDelegate *itDelegate = new  ItemDelegate;
ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(itDelegate);
```

It is good example, so you can do all another things, for example:

```
if(data == model->data(cur, Qt::EditRole).toString())
{
    //model->setData(index, "wrong");
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Try again.");
    msgBox.exec();
    return;
}
```

and so on.

Of course if there are many items in view, it can be slow, so you can use QProgressDialog to show user how many times you need:

```
QProgressDialog progress("Checking...", "Searching", 0, model->rowCount(), 0);
for(int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); i++)
{
    progress.setValue(i);
    QModelIndex cur = model->index(i,column);
    qDebug() << data << model->data(cur, Qt::EditRole).toString();
    if(data == model->data(cur, Qt::EditRole).toString())
    {
        model->setData(index, "wrong");
        return;
    }
    if (progress.wasCanceled())
       return;
}
progress.close();
```