# Set a column in QTableWidget to unique in Qt 5

Tags: qt, qt5, unique, qtablewidget

I could not figure out how to set a column in a QTableWidget to have all unique entries. Is this even possible?

Comment: [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724732/ensure-unique-value-for-column-in-qtableview) to this one may help you. But that one is about QTableView.

Comment: How do you want it to behave? Fail when a non-unique item is added in code? Or not allow the user to edit the value to a non-unique one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model should ensure the data is unique by returning false from setData() call when trying to input non-unique value in an item.
[Look at this problem](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/60708-Ensure-unique-value-for-column-in-QTableView)

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some simple example. I am beginner and wanna to add files to a table (there is no sense to store twice the same path). For educational reason it would be nice if you add in example reaction when data is not unique.